# How to put link in twenty fourteen theme?

Tags: posts, theme-twenty-fourteen

I need to put link with image at the end of post page. 
What I am looking for is that at the end of each new post, I need to have small image with link that opens in a new window. How to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about same image for all posts? or you have to upload image from the backend?

Comment: Yes, same link and same image on all posts. Directly under article, and above comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit and put any content you want on "single.php" file in the theme folder.

Comment: It's OK now. I found a way. I need to change content.php, not single.php. Thank you, you helped me much.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this... Two most popular ways would be:

### Modifying the theme files

You can find the template file in your theme that is responsible for displaying these posts/pages and add your HTML code in it.

Use [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to find correct file.

Remember: You should NEVER modify theme files directly. If you do, your changes will be lost after the theme gets updated... You should create [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead and do your modifications there...

### Using `the_content` filter

If you want to add some HTML code to the end of posts, then you can also use `the_content` filter.

```
function add_my_code_after_post_content( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $content .= "<div>My custom HTML code goes here</div>";
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_my_code_after_post_content' );
```